# Why stretching body do not have acceleration?

Tags: elasticity

I was studying elasticity and my teacher said as we are streching it, we can take F(elastic) = F(ext) as acceleration is zero. My efforts are that acceleration is only zero when the object is perfectly elastic like steel but not when it is inelastic like rubber band.

Comment: Every solid is elastic for small deformations; I don't know what distinction you're drawing between steel and rubber. Your teacher probably meant simply that there isn't a net force on an object between stretched by equal and opposite forces; therefore, the center of mass isn't accelerated away.